# Starting project on Windows and now cloning on Mac made disappear iOS Bundle Options tabs

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

As the title says, we were developing a Xamarin Forms app on Windows Platform. Now we need to implement the iOS version so we cloned the solution from git to our Mac machine. But if I go to Project.iOS > right click > Options then the window does not contain the iOS tabs such as iOS Bundle Options, iOS IPA Options and so on. You can look the normal behaviour and this particular case in attached images. 
How is it possibile? How can i solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: that appears to be the project options for a .NET Library, not an iOS project.  Are you sure VS Mac is up to date?  Can you compare the csproj file for the iOS project on the two machines to be sure they are identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compared the .csproj file of my project with the .csproj file of a new project created on the Mac and they seems different only for this line:

Wrong .csproj line:

```
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
```

Right .csproj line:

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

So I changed that line and now it works.